# React & NodeJS shows the URI is malformed error

Tags: reactjs

I recently moved my workspace to Linux centOS from Windows10. When I run this code in Windows 10. It works and I am able to upload file to the server. But when I change the environment to CentOS. It still show the output but it does not send file to the server and show error "URI is malformed"

here are my codes

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';
class UploadPDF extends React.Component {

constructor(props) 
{
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {          
         images: [],
         imageUrls: [],
         message: ''
    }
}

selectImages = (event) => 
{
    let images = []
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) 
    {
        images[i] = event.target.files.item(i);
    }
    images = images.filter(image => image.name.match(/\.(pdf)$/))
    let message = `${images.length} valid File(s) selected`
    this.setState({ images, message })
}

uploadImages = () => 
{
  MySwal.fire('File Uploaded','The File Is Uploaded!','success'
  );
    const uploaders = this.state.images.map(image => 
        {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append("image", image, image.name);
            // Make an AJAX upload request using Axios
            return axios.post(BASE_URL + 'upload', data)
                .then(response => 
                    {
                        this.setState(
                            {
                                imageUrls: [ response.data.imageUrl, ...this.state.imageUrls ]
                            });
                    })
        });

    axios.all(uploaders).then(() => 
    {
        console.log('done');
    }).catch(err => alert(err.message));
}


render() {
    console.log("Header - Rendered");
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="py-5 text-center">
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h1>Upload File</h1>
                        <hr/>
                        <p className="lead">Only PDF</p>                        
                        <input className="form-control " type="file" onChange={this.selectImages} multiple />
                        <p className="text-info">{this.state.message}</p>           
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onClick={this.uploadImages}>Submit</button>                                   
                    </div>                            
                </div>                         
            </div>     
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default UploadPDF;
```

This is the code I am stuck and dunno what to do. any links or suggestion ?

Comment: `BASE_URL + 'upload'` becomes `http://localhost:5000upload`. there is a forward slash missing between the origin and the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on but my guess is you're combining the string in `BASE_URL` with `"upload"` so you wind up trying to post to `http://localhost:5000upload` rather than `http://localhost:5000/upload`.

Try adding a trailing slash on BASE_URL and see if that fixes your problem.

This said, I'm not sure why the OS would make a difference.

Comment: Omg Thanks. I ve been trying to search online for days. But the solution is only by adding /  at the infront of the upload. Thank You So Much It works !